# DateTime and String Validation

Tags: c#, validation, datetime

I have a simple question about DateTime in c#.

I have a textbox where I ask the user to input a date.

I want to validate that the textbox is not empty before parsing the string to a datetime to validate if the date is in the right format.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
String strStartDate = txtStartDate.txt;

DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Parse(strStartDate);
```

I have other text boxes for the names and such and I also validate if they are empty with a if statement like this (same if statement to validate if strStartDate is empty):

```
    if (strFirstName.Trim() == "")
    {

        txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

        errorMessage = errorMessage + "First Name may not be empty. ";
    }

    else
    {

        txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

    }
```

The debugger stops as soon as I try the submit button, it says that String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Is there a way to see if the string is empty before validating the DateTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use TryParse:

```
        string SomeDate = "1/1/2012";
        DateTime dt;
        var success = DateTime.TryParse(SomeDate, out dt);
```

Then you can check success to see if it was a valid date or not.  This will protect you from any invalid date string, not just an empty or null string.

Answer (score 0):

[String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) will do what you want